# Explaining importance of interaction that is statistically insigificant

Tags: regression, modeling, interaction, model

Consider the following dataset composed of two different groups blue and red which are observed over time. The super-imposed lines are regression lines fit to each group separately, i.e. for each group we fit a model $y=a + b \times Time$. In my mind, it is very clear that there is an interaction between Time and the grouping of the point, but when I fit a single model to the entire data: $y=a + b \times Time + c \times Group + d \times Time\times Group$, the third interaction term always shows up as not significant. This is based on the p-value that I get in R (for reference, it's around 0.55).

My question is, how should one explain this phenomenon? The red group is clearly under represented at both extremes and if one were to take a hold-out approach to model selection, it is clear that the model with interaction should always out-perform a model without the interaction. Is there a rigorous way of arguing why the p-value from the hypothesis test computed by R is not reliable in this scenario though ?
[image]

**update**
Based on the suggestion by @Frank Harrell, I generated the second plot.  [image]

Comment: "*...it is clear that the model with interaction should always out-perform a model without the interaction. Is there a rigorous way of arguing why the p-value from the hypothesis test computed by R is not reliable in this scenario though?*" Could you present some evidence for these assumptions? It is not at all obvious to me from the plot that the blue and red points show different patterns.

Comment: "Statistical significance" means very little and uses thresholds that are entirely arbitrary.  I think you are attaching too much importance to it.  Compute the confidence interval on the double difference (interaction effect), say at 2010 vs. 1990.

Answer (score 0):

The p-value tells you that you cannot conclude that the blue and red lines have different slopes. Looking at the graph, I think that makes sense - the lines aren't exactly parallel, but they look pretty close to parallel.

> Is there a rigorous way of arguing why the p-value from the hypothesis
> test computed by R is not reliable in this scenario?

You could look at the standard error on the estimated red slope and blue slope. I suspect you'll see that the uncertainty in estimating each slope is big compared to the difference between them. But this is not a reason to disbelieve the p-value; it's a way to satisfy yourself that the p-value is correct.

By the way, I have sometimes heard the incorrect idea that *the interaction tells you whether time depends on group*. By any chance is that what you mean when you say it is clear to you that the interaction should be significant?

Comment: I don't think I made this interpretation, my understanding of the interaction effect is that it allows one to differentiate between the rates of change (with respect to year) for the two groups